# can't convert sql to sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

this query was made for a php 5.7 script and does not function anymore, my provider is one.com and this is what they use: PHP Versie: 7.1.30
MySQL versie: 10.3.14-MariaDB-1:10.3.14+maria~bionic

Been already here numerous times for answers and usually i get it fixed, but this one is breaking my head! Tried DB Fiddle and they Always come up with the same fault:

> Query Error: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "KEY": syntax error ,and,Query Error: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "unsigned": syntax error

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bo_hourly` (
  `time` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `strikes` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `st_strikes` int(8) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bo_stat` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `strikes` mediumint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxdist` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mindist` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '999999',
  `maxstrikes` mediumint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxtime` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxusers` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `st_strikes` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `st_mindist` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '999999',
  `st_maxdist` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `st_max` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `st_maxtime` int(15) NOT NULL,
  KEY `time` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I know it must be simple but something near 'key' and 'unsigned' seems to be wrong, if anyone could help me on the way, perhaps i am searching too farfetched...

Comment: Start by reading https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: There is no `unsigned` `mediumint`. There is also need to specify the size with `mediumint`. You could really just do `maxstrikes INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`. I agree with @shawn you should familiarize yourself with sqlites CREATE TABLE statement, as well as the data types and how they work. It's definitely not 1:1 with mysql.

Comment: indeed @JNevill MySQL allowes "alot" more datatypes/options in the `CREATE TABLE` statement and column clauses..

Comment: Also read https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html which explains what sqlite treats all those `int(6)` , etc types as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the minimum changes that would be required for a close conversion (see notes) would result in the following code (bar the comment to indicate the code that has been ADDED) :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bo_hourly` (
  `time` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `strikes` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `st_strikes` int(8) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE /*KEY `time`*/ (`time`)
) /*ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1*/;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bo_stat` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `strikes` mediumint(11) /*unsigned*/ NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxdist` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mindist` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '999999',
  `maxstrikes` mediumint(11) /*unsigned*/ NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxtime` int(15) /*unsigned*/ NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxusers` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `st_strikes` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `st_mindist` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '999999',
  `st_maxdist` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `st_max` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `st_maxtime` int(15) NOT NULL/*,
  KEY `time` (`date`)
*/)/* ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8*/;

-- ADDED
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `time` ON `bo_stat`(`date`);
```

Basically

- SQlite doesn't have the KEY keyword rather indexes are either implied (e.g. using UNIQUE) or explicitly defined (as per the added line).
- **unsigned** becomes a syntax error because of a nuance with values enclosed in parenthesises, it expects them to be the last value of the column type (e.g. mediumint unsigned would actually work). As such unsigned has been commented out.
- **ENGINE=MyISAM** is not a valid clause in SQLite (commented out)
- **DEFAULT CHARSET** is not a supported clause in SQLite (commented out).

  - SQLite character encoding support is limited, [PRAGMA encoding](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding) explains a little.
- The final comma indicating an additional clause, has been commented out.
- The final closing parenthesis has not been commented out

Comment: Thanks, MikeT! The query returns no errors, but it is giving back an empty result set. This query is attached to a PHP-script written in 5.3 and my provider is using 7.1 so i must look deeper into the for that!

Answer (score 0):

A valid SQLite code can look like below which matches your MySQL code.

Notice that the `int(6)` and `int(8)` in MySQL still store the same (max) information, as that is depending on [zerofill](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) ...

`int(6)` does not store a max off `999999` which you might be thinking when i look into the defaults.. 
if you want or need to limit max values i suggest you looking into `CHECK Constraint` which is also explained in the [CREATE TABLE ... syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bo_hourly (
  time int NOT NULL,
  strikes int NOT NULL,
  st_strikes int NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (time)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bo_stat (
  date date NOT NULL,
  strikes int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  maxdist int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  mindist int NOT NULL DEFAULT '999999',
  maxstrikes int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  maxtime int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  maxusers int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  st_strikes int NOT NULL,
  st_mindist int NOT NULL DEFAULT '999999',
  st_maxdist int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  st_max int NOT NULL,
  st_maxtime int NOT NULL
);

# There is no column time in the bo_stat table
# CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS time ON bo_stat(time);
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c8GBV4d4hA97QwxaFmv9cq/0)

Comment: Raymond, also a big thank you, but see comment above!